# Navigation Menu width resize in atahualpa wordpress theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation, menubar

How can I resize the menu size in my website http://www.onechangedlife.com/.
I am using Atahualpa theme.
I am Attaching the image.
Please Help ![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find this class

```css
div#menu1 ul.rMenu li a:link,
div#menu1 ul.rMenu li a:hover,
div#menu1 ul.rMenu li a:visited,
div#menu1 ul.rMenu li a:active
```

Current font-size is 20px - adjust it as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks!! But its not with the font size I guess.The problem is actually at the right hand corner the menu bar is slightly above and below the background.I need to fix that.Please help

Comment: Find this class

ul.rMenu-hor li

Remove the below 2 lines
margin-bottom:-1px;
Margin-top:-1px;

That works!!